# Docker fastapi unable to connect to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I'm new to docker and fastapi and I'm trying to connect fastapi with mysql service but it always say that it cannot connect to mysql in the logs. What am I missing here?

**.env file**

```
    API_PATH='api'
API_VERSION='v1'

FASTAPI_CONTAINER_NAME='app_fastapi'
FASTAPI_PORT=8000

REDIS_CONTAINER_NAME='app_redis'
REDIS_HOST='app_redis'
REDIS_PORT=8001

MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME='app_mysql'
MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME='fastapi_db'
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='P@ssw0rd'
MYSQL_USER='fastapi_mysql_admin'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='P@ssw0rd'
MYSQL_HOST='app_mysql'
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

**docker-compose file**

```
    version: "3.9"  # Specify a compatible Docker Compose version

services:
  fastapi:
    build:
      context: ./fastapi  # Build your FastAPI app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use your app's Dockerfile
    container_name: ${FASTAPI_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${FASTAPI_PORT}:${FASTAPI_PORT}"  # Expose port 8000 for the FastAPI app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on: # Ensure both mysql and redis starts first
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always
    tty: true
    networks:
      - backend

  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./mysql  # Build from the current directory
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use the specific Dockerfile
    container_name: ${MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:${MYSQL_PORT}"  # Expose port 3306 for database access
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-p${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 7s
    tty: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
  
  redis:
    build:
      context: ./redis  # Build from the current directory
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use the specific Dockerfile
    container_name: ${REDIS_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}"  # Expose Redis port
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 7s
    tty: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
```

**database.py**

```
    import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from os import environ as env

user = env['MYSQL_USER']
password = env['MYSQL_PASSWORD']
host = env['MYSQL_HOST']
port = env['MYSQL_PORT']
database = env['MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME']

DATABASE_URL = 'mysql+pymysql://{}@{}/{}:{}?charset=utf8'.format(user, host, database, port)

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from os import environ as env
from app.modules.todo import router as TodoRouter
app = FastAPI()
apiPath = '/' + env['API_PATH'] + '/' + env['API_VERSION']
# routers
app.include_router(TodoRouter.router, prefix=apiPath + '/todo', tags=['Todo'])
```

**todo/router.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from app.database import get_db
from app.modules.todo.data_models import TodoRequestModel

router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/')
def create(todo: TodoRequestModel, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return TodoController.create(todo, db)
```

**On docker start**

[image]

[image]

**Docker container log when /post endpoint is hit**

```
- INFO:     172.31.0.1:37760 - "POST /api/v1/todo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
- ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
- Traceback (most recent call last):
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 796, in _connect
-     self._get_server_information()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 994, in _get_server_information
-     self.server_charset = charset_by_id(lang).name
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py", line 34, in by_id
-     return self._by_id[id]
- KeyError: 255
- 
- During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
- 
- Traceback (most recent call last):
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
-     return fn()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
-     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
-     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
-     rec = pool._do_get()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
-     return self._create_connection()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
-     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
-     self.__connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 665, in __connect
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
-     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
-     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
-     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
-     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 634, in __init__
-     self._connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 817, in _connect
-     raise OperationalError(
- pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (255)")
- 
- The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
- 
- Traceback (most recent call last):
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
-     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
-     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
-     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
-     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
-     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
-     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
-     await app(scope, receive, sender)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 762, in __call__
-     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 782, in app
-     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
-     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
-     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
-     await app(scope, receive, sender)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
-     response = await func(request)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 299, in app
-     raise e
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 294, in app
-     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 193, in run_endpoint_function
-     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
-     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
-     return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 2134, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
-     return await future
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 851, in run
-     result = context.run(func, *args)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/router.py", line 23, in create
-     return TodoController.create(todo, db)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/controller.py", line 17, in create
-     return TodoService.create(student, db)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/repository.py", line 62, in create
-     db.commit()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1431, in commit
-     self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
-     self._prepare_impl()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
-     self.session.flush()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3363, in flush
-     self._flush(objects)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3502, in _flush
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3463, in _flush
-     flush_context.execute()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
-     rec.execute(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
-     util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 211, in save_obj
-     for (
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 372, in _organize_states_for_save
-     for state, dict_, mapper, connection in _connections_for_states(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1711, in _connections_for_states
-     connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 626, in connection
-     return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 735, in _connection_for_bind
-     conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 747, in _connection_for_bind
-     conn = bind.connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3204, in connect
-     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
-     else engine.raw_connection()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3283, in raw_connection
-     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3253, in _wrap_pool_connect
-     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2100, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
-     util.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
-     return fn()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
-     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
-     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
-     rec = pool._do_get()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
-     return self._create_connection()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
-     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
-     self.__connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 665, in __connect
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
-     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
-     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
-     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
-     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 634, in __init__
-     self._connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 817, in _connect
-     raise OperationalError(
- sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (255)")
- (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I've tried adding a password in the database connection string but gives me a different error like the following

```
DATABASE_URL = "mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
        user,
        password,
        host,
        port,
        database
    )
```

**new log**

```
- INFO:     172.31.0.1:52082 - "POST /api/v1/todo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
- ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
- Traceback (most recent call last):
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
-     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
-     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
-     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
-     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
-     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
-     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
-     await app(scope, receive, sender)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 762, in __call__
-     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 782, in app
-     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
-     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
-     await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
-     raise exc
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
-     await app(scope, receive, sender)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
-     response = await func(request)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 299, in app
-     raise e
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 294, in app
-     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 193, in run_endpoint_function
-     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
-     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
-     return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 2134, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
-     return await future
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 851, in run
-     result = context.run(func, *args)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/router.py", line 23, in create
-     return TodoController.create(todo, db)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/controller.py", line 17, in create
-     return TodoService.create(student, db)
-   File "/app/fastapi/app/modules/todo/repository.py", line 62, in create
-     db.commit()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1431, in commit
-     self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
-     self._prepare_impl()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
-     self.session.flush()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3363, in flush
-     self._flush(objects)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3502, in _flush
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3463, in _flush
-     flush_context.execute()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
-     rec.execute(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
-     util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 211, in save_obj
-     for (
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 372, in _organize_states_for_save
-     for state, dict_, mapper, connection in _connections_for_states(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1711, in _connections_for_states
-     connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 626, in connection
-     return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 735, in _connection_for_bind
-     conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 747, in _connection_for_bind
-     conn = bind.connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3204, in connect
-     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
-     else engine.raw_connection()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3283, in raw_connection
-     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3250, in _wrap_pool_connect
-     return fn()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
-     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
-     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
-     rec = pool._do_get()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
-     return self._create_connection()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
-     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
-     self.__connect()
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 665, in __connect
-     with util.safe_reraise():
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
-     compat.raise_(
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
-     raise exception
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
-     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
-     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
-     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
-   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
-     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
- TypeError: Connection.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

Comment: I don't believe the docker-compose.yml file itself will use environment variables from the .env file.  They are passed into the container.

Comment: It seems it doesn't take the `env` variables into the container. Though, it could also be that the `get_db` function is not properly initiated. I would save it in a variable at the module level, initialize it at `startup` and then import from there everywhere else

Answer (score 1):

First, any container that wants to read data from an `env` file must have an `env_file` section and the path of the env file must be specified inside it. So set this for `mysql` and `redis` services as well.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    env_file:
      - .env
  redis:
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Second, in the `mysql` service inside docker compose, you read the name of the container from the env file, and inside the env file, you have set this value equal to `app_mysql`.

```
MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME='app_mysql'
```

Since routing in the docker compose network is something like DNS, you must set the value of MYSQL_HOST equal to the name of the mysql container so that your fastapi service can connect to the mysql container.

```
MYSQL_HOST='app_mysql'
```

Comment: @Hammed I've updated the .env file and docker-compose file and database url string but still got same error "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' (255)".

Comment: Have you try to create the database first and then connect to it? 

Note: The trace-back of your first error contains a link to SQLAlchemy website that says It's an [OperationalError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-e3q8). Following that link will take you to the [Dealing with Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#pool-disconnects) page. Reading both of them may help you solve your problem.